# How to next activity after progress indicator in Flutter WebView?

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I am trying to build a webview project, I want to go to next page after loading indicator, but it's not working, is there anything i missed or mess up?  I want after loading indicator my loaded webviewsite will show automatically. 
I am trying to build a webview project, I want to go to next page after loading indicator, but it's not working, is there anything i missed or mess up?  I want after loading indicator my loaded webviewsite will show automatically

Here is my code-

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/circular_percent_indicator.dart';
import 'package:web2app/widgets/drawer.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

const String flutterUrl = 'https://flutter.dev/';
const String wikiUrl = 'https://google.com/';

class X extends StatefulWidget {
  XState createState() => XState();
}

class XState extends State<X> {
  WebViewController _controller;

  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  _back() async {
    if (await _controller.canGoBack()) {
      await _controller.goBack();
    }
  }

  _forward() async {
    if (await _controller.canGoForward()) {
      await _controller.goForward();
    }
  }

  _loadPage() async {
    var url = await _controller.currentUrl();
    _controller.loadUrl(
      url == flutterUrl ? wikiUrl : flutterUrl,
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
          title: Text('Web2App'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios), onPressed: _back),
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios), onPressed: _forward),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: DrawerPage(),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _loadPage,
          child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                isLoading
                    ? Container(
                        child: CircularPercentIndicator(
                          radius: 120.0,
                          lineWidth: 13.0,
                          animation: true,
                          animationDuration: 4500,
                          percent: 1,
                          footer: new Text(
                            "Loading...",
                            style: new TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17.0),
                          ),
                          circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
                          progressColor: Colors.purple,
                        ),
                      )
                    : WebView(
                        key: Key('webview'),
                        initialUrl: flutterUrl,
                        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                        onWebViewCreated:
                            (WebViewController webViewController) {
                          _controller = webViewController;
                        },
                      )
              ]),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a FutureBuilder, I recommend this amazing official Flutter video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RA-vLF_vnng

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got `isLoading` set to true without ever changing it.

```
`void initState() {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    super.initState();
  }`
```

But then you haven't set `isLoading` to false again to load the next screen

```
`isLoading ? Container()
//all your code for loading screen
//you could set the state of isLoading to false here
    : WebView()
    //All your WebView code`
```

You're saying if `isLoading == true` then keep loading, but nothing sets it to false inside the widget.

Comment: I tried but it's not working, i mean to say i want to redirect webview after loading screen. Like i want to show loading screen for 5 sec then it will close automatically and will show webview.

Comment: `class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadData();
  }

  Future<Timer> loadData() async {
    return new Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), onDoneLoading);
  }
  onDoneLoading() async {
    Navigator.of(context)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
  }`


This has a timer with a duration for the loading screen(in this case the SplashScreen) and you can set it to whatever amount of time you want.

Comment: Not editing correctly on here - but you can space things out to understand the process. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work fine with you

```
class WebViewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final String selectedUrl;

  WebViewScreen({@required this.title, @required this.selectedUrl});

  @override
  _WebViewScreenState createState() => _WebViewScreenState();
}

class _WebViewScreenState extends State<WebViewScreen> {
  Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();
  bool isLoading = true;

  num position = 1;

  final key = UniqueKey();

  doneLoading(String A) {
    setState(() {
      position = 0;
    });
  }

  startLoading(String A) {
    setState(() {
      position = 1;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: IndexedStack(index: position, children: <Widget>[
          WebView(
            initialUrl: widget.selectedUrl,
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            key: key,
            onPageFinished: doneLoading,
            onPageStarted: startLoading,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _controller.complete(webViewController);
            },
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Center(child: CustomAppProgressBar),
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```